# How to Redraw Canvas Objects to Larger Canvas using Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

In my page i have small and large canvas,What my user see is a small canvas with the default line in the middle.. When the user move it, i need to redraw it in a larger canvas so when the user export it, its a big image.

Take a look my fiddle sample

```
Links: http://jsfiddle.net/mailightkun/kahsomv7/10/
```

Comment: you want something like drag drop in between this two canvas, am i right?

Comment: Not Totally drag and drop, its more on replication.. What user do in the small canvas it should reflect in the larger canvas..

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in the past.

This function clone all object from a canvas to another and permits you to specify a left and top offset:

```
function cloneObjects(from_canvas, to_canvas, o_top, o_left) {

    var objects = from_canvas.getObjects();
    for (var i in objects) {

        var object = fabric.util.object.clone(objects[i]);
        var x = object.x;
        var y = object.y;
        var left = object.left;
        var top = object.top;
        object.x = o_left + x;
        object.y = o_top + y;
        object.left = o_left + left;
        object.top = o_top + top;

        object.name += '-export';

        object.setCoords();

        object.selectable = false;

        to_canvas.add(object);


    }

    to_canvas.calcOffset();
    to_canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
}
```

Let me know if this suits your requirements.